# pandas Selecting/sampling at different interval frequencies

Tags: pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array, dataframe, broadcasting

I have a 2d array/DF

```
>>> X_df.shape
Out[36]: (138, 2164)
```

Each row of this array has values uptill a given column (different for all rows) followed by nans:

```
>>> X_df.head(1).T
Out[28]: 
          Row1
0       1208.380
1       1207.600
2       1207.400
...          ...
247     1213.030
248     1212.950
249     1213.000
...          ...
1914         nan
1915         nan
1916         nan
```

I need to create another array/DF Y of shape (138, n), which has n (=3 or 5 or 10) values from each row of X_df selected equally spaced. So if X_df row 1 has 100 elements, and row 2 had 50, then for n=10, Y row 1= every 10th element from row 1 of X_df and Y row 2= every 5th element from row 2 of X_df.

I created a function to get an array of number of values in each index.

```
>>> last= X_df.apply(last_index,axis=1)
>>> last
Out[34]: 
Row1     360
...      ...  
Row45    1438
```

What might be the best way of getting the required Y array/DF? Want to avoid loops here. I tried `X_df[::last]` but it gave an error `"ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"`
I looked into `np.meshgrid` but that didn't seem relevant. Also looked at `DataFrame.sample` but that seems to be useful for random sampling only.